# Ergonomic Keyboard for OS Sierra

Tags: mac, keyboard, hardware-recommendation

I recently switched from PC (many years, many Dells) to an iMac. I'm learning to love it. I do not have any issues with my wrists, etc., but I am a very fast typist and am used to an ergonomic keyboard (formerly used one from Microsoft).

I absolutely despise the Apple Magic Keyboard, however I cannot find an ergonomic keyboard that's compatible with OS Sierra 10.12.6. Wireless or wired, I'll take ANYTHING ergonomic.

Has anyone found one anywhere? I'm weary from 3 months of searching.

Comment: Any USB keyboard should work, including those sold by Microsoft. What kind of incompatibility did you find?

Comment: None have Mac specifications high enough for OS Sierra. And LOTS of reviews on line about malfunctions on the Microsoft keyboards. Thanks, though!

Comment: Not exactly. I've been using Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic and love it. However, at the company I work now everything is Mac-stuff and you have no choice. The Microsoft keyboard just does not work. It doubles sequences of keystrokes, misses keystrokes and the mouse cursor just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I know of and can recommend two different ones because I had two employees that, due to medical issues needed these keyboards.  One was a photographer and the other was a programmer.  Both swore by them.

- [Goldtouch Ergonomic Keyboard for Mac](http://radnex.us/goldtouch-ergo-keyboard-mac)
- [Kenisis Freestyle Keyboard](http://radnex.us/kinesis-ergo-keyboards-mac)

A simple [Internet search](https://www.bing.com/search?q=ergonomic%20keyboard%20for%20mac&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN) yields a number of results.

That said, the Microsoft ergonomic keyboard works just fine under on a Mac.  In fact, I have both the Apple keyboard and a Logitech K380 (Windows) keyboard hooked up simultaneously and both work just fine.

You just have to be aware that the Windows key functions as the <kbd>Command</kbd> key.

Comment: Also, if you don't like the fact that the ⌘ and ⌥ keys are switched, **and those keys are identically shaped** (which will unfortunately probably not be the case on an ergonomic keyboard), you may be able to physically switch them. I did this with my Logitech G610. Even if you can't physically switch the keycaps, though, you can still swap their function in System Preferences. (You'll still have to do this even if you do switch the keycaps, of course, since the keyboard can't tell.)

Comment: Thank you! I'll check out both. I'm fine with the Command key issue and can either work with them or find a work-around. Appreciate your help!